# Why to use 'errno' at all?

Tags: c, std, libc

I'm a CS student at the Technion, I have just learned of `errno` variable and c-style function calls.
This makes me wonder, if c-style syscalls use registers to return a value, why should anyone use `errno` at all?

Comment: Wasn't `errno`  a C stdlib thing instead of having to do anythnig with syscalls and Linux?

Comment: @Joey I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Errno is a 30-35 year old design decision (or was it older?); trying to understand it now, in the context of today's (vastly more powerful) machines and (vastly more complex and more capable) languages is probably not going to help much. It is what it is.

Comment: Please do not use unless I give permission! (I have been stared at by many C programmers when introducing myself...)

Comment: @Erno: Are you really a 30-35 year old design decision?

Comment: @Catcall, I am a bit older than that but the design goes waaaay back ;)

Comment: @FredNurk FYI the errno is the main source of a messages about an errors on GNU/Linux. Almost everything bad that could occur — network, file system, permission — is returned via errno. And IMAO Windows®'s surrogate «GetLastError()» and «FormatMesage()» versus standard «errno» and «perror()/strerror()» is an overkill.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main reason for using `errno` is to give more information about the error condition.

This is especially useful in situations where most (or even *all*) possible return values of a function are actually *valid* return values.

Consider the `fopen()` function, which returns a pointer to a `FILE`. Every possible return value is also a valid return value, except `NULL`. So `fopen()` returns `NULL` on failure. But then you can't tell what exactly made the function fail. Hence, `fopen()` uses `errno` to denote the exact error condition, i.e. the file doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to read it, or the system is out of memory, or whatever.

You can think of `errno` as a global variable (which it used to be until threads became popular). Nowadays, `errno` is usually a macro wrapping a function call returning the error condition. But this is just C's way of implementing thread-specific global variables.

The alternatives to `errno` are less comfortable:

You could supply a function with a pointer to an `int`, and the function can store its error condition there. `strtod()` is a good example of this technique. But this makes the API more complicated and hence less desirable. Also, it forces the programmer to define a new `int`, which is annoying if you don't care if the function fails.

In languages that allow more than one return value (and don't feature exceptions), it's common to return two values: one for the actual result and another to denote the error condition. In languages like Go, you see code like the following:

```
result, ok = foo();
if (ok) {
    // handle error denoted by "ok"
}
```

Don't trust people who claim that `errno` is an "old" technique and hence to be avoided. The machine you're programming is far older than `errno` or even C, and nobody has ever complained about that.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.
I still not sure why only sys calls used that variable and not all user-space function

Comment: Actually, a lot of functions from the C standard library use `errno`, e.g. `malloc()` or `fopen()`. Do you know the difference between system calls, *standard* library functions and library functions?

Comment: I question your assertion that nobody has ever complained about C :)

Comment: This might be reasonable for some high-level API, but consider Linux syscall warper API, the actual syscall will always return a int through a register, negative values indicate different types of errors and non-negtive values indicate success. Using errno for such interfaces makes a hard-to-use anti-humanity state machine, instead, direct return value would make API closer to real kernel ABI and easier to understand.

Comment: Exceptions are not always better than error numbers, especially when the error is supposed  to be dealt with by its immediate, that is, the error is actually checked and handled ON THE SPOT.

Comment: What about linux APIs, e.g. `int fd = open(...);`? A valid fd is positive so there's plenty of room to convey the error code through a negative value, yet `errno` is still used...

Comment: @TomekSowiński `errno` for `open(2)` is the result of wrapping of actual Linux-specific system call by glibc to provide POSIX interface of the standard system call.

Comment: @Ruslan ok, so it's posix not linux. Still doesn't explain *why* posix didn't use the negative handle value to convey the error code.

Answer (score 11):

The design of the C library was done a long time ago at the same time as early Unix. Use of a separate error code is not an uncommon pattern (Win32 has the similar GetLastError()). And it has superficial advantages.

If you decide you want a class of functions to have a return value that is commonly used, then you can't easily use that to return errors. For example, imagine a hypothetical API

```
mytime_t t = get_current_time();
```

The common use of this API is to get time. But perhaps it can fail in some circumstances, and you get detailed error information from errno. This makes the API code a bit easier to read and write than if you had to say

```
mytime_t t=0;
errno_t e = get_current_time(&t);
```

So superficially, errno-type systems are appealing. However, the separation of error state from the actual function call leads to lots of problems. Modern environments make errno_t a per-thread variable (removing the most obvious source of problems), but you still face the problem that if you do

```
mytime_t t = get_current_time();
mysize_t s = get_window_size();
```

then you destroy the errno from the first function invisibly. This gets even more complex when code can run in error paths or where one function is implemented in terms of others. Lots of saving and restoring errno values ensures. I think it's pretty well accepted now that such systems are fragile and undesirable.

Many folks use exceptions which carry errors outside the explicit parameter/return set (many C++ programmers make this choice). Folks working in exception-free languages or environments tend to bite the bullet and reserve the return value for an error and always provide output through parameters (COM makes this choice with HRESULTs).

Comment: Though "errno_t e; mytime_t t = get_current_time(&e);" makes a better comparison.

Answer (score 5):

`errno` is a complicated thing, in that it is an historic interface that probably nowadays nobody would design like that. In addition on most systems it nowadays only looks like a variable, it ain't one. Usually it is implemented as a macro that hides a function call, and that function call returns a thread specific error condition.

Comment: Can I use this for my Bio? I am quite complicated... (Sorry couldn't resist ;-) )

Comment: @Erno, no, no, no. First get your spelling corrected, or invent a story why on early unixes you had to use a 5 letter name because of storage restriction or so. You wouldn't get away with it as easy as this.

Comment: my spelling software returns an errno when I spell errno because I added erno to the dictionary. Perhaps Erno should cause an  errno because it is spelled wrong...

Answer (score 2):

The best example that I can think of is the stdio function `fopen`, which returns NULL at failure and the only way to find out why it failed is through errno and/or perror.

There must be other examples. This is just what sprung in to mind at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer.
What I meant, is why does (for example) fopen uses errno from the first place?

Comment: Alternatively it could have had another parameter to store the possible error. Something like fopen( ... int *err). If you're asking why they chose one method over the other, I can't answer that at the moment.