# NASM x86_64: File opening (SYS_OPEN) error list?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, errno

I'm coding a linux x64 assembly program that read a file and I want to handle errors like File Not Found or permission errors.

## Where can I find a list of SYS_OPEN error codes?

### Approaches to find codes (kinda fun)

My code to open a file:

```
SYS_OPEN    equ 2
O_RDONLY    equ 0

section .data
    filename db "file.txt", 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, SYS_OPEN
    mov rdi, filename
    mov rsi, O_RDONLY
    mov rdx, 0644o
    syscall

    [...]
```

When the file is successfully opened the RAX register points to the `file descriptor` (positive integer), if fails RAX point to an error (negative integer). I managed to raise a permission error by removing all permissions for all users:

```sh
chmod 0000 file.txt
```

This causes an error with code `-13`. By deleting the file, I managed to get error `-2`. Where can I find a list of SYS_OPEN error codes?

PS: Maybe my googling skills are rusty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Linux system call return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751614/what-are-the-return-values-of-system-calls-in-assembly) from `-4095` to `-1` are `-errno` codes.**  (The actual highest error number that Linux has actually defined is currently about `133`, `EHWPOISON`, but that's the official range.)

**`strace ./myprog`** can decode them for you so you don't need to actually write error checking in your toy programs when playing around with system calls.

For example:

```
$ strace touch /tmp/xyjklj/bar
...  (dynamic linker / process startup stuff)

openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/xyjklj/bar", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
utimensat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/xyjklj/bar", NULL, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

... (more system calls as touch(1) finds a locale-specific set of error messages and prints
```

(The `-1` is what the libc wrapper function actually returns; the errno code is what strace decoded from the asm syscall return value, which the glibc wrapper will store in `errno`.  When using raw system calls in asm, you don't have to waste instructions doing that.  But strace will still say "-1", not the numeric error code)

---

### Documentation of most ways `SYS_open` can fail

Each system call man page documents which error codes that particular system call can fail with, and in which cases that can happen.  (Those list **aren't fully exhaustive**, for example not covering weird things a specific filesystem like NFS could return, like `EMULTIHOP` (see comments).)

For your case, see [the ERRORs section of the `open(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html#ERRORS).  e.g. there are several entries for `ENOENT`, covering all the cases which can lead to that return value.

> - `ENOENT` - `O_CREAT` is not set and the named file does not exist.
> - `ENOENT` - A directory component in pathname does not exist or is a
>   dangling symbolic link.
> - `ENOENT` - pathname refers to a nonexistent directory, `O_TMPFILE` and
>   one of `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` were specified in flags, but
>   this kernel version does not provide the O_TMPFILE
>   functionality.

(Spoiler alert, `2` is `ENOENT`, so `-2` is `-ENOENT`.)

There are of course lots of other fun ways that pathname and file access stuff (and `open(2)` in particular) can error, including:

> - **`EACCES` (`-13`)** - The requested access to the file is not allowed, or search
>   permission is denied for one of the directories in the
>   path prefix of `pathname`, or the file did not exist yet and
>   write access to the parent directory is not allowed.  (See
>   also path_resolution(7).)
> - `EFAULT` - `pathname` points outside your accessible address space.
> - `ENAMETOOLONG` -
>   `pathname` was too long.
> - `EBUSY` -  `O_EXCL` was specified in flags and `pathname` refers to a
>   block device that is in use by the system (e.g., it is
>   mounted).
>   [this would require root, otherwise you'd get EACCESS]
> - `ETXTBSY` -  `pathname` refers to an executable image which is currently
>   being executed and write access was requested.
> - `EWOULDBLOCK` -
>   The `O_NONBLOCK` flag was specified, and an incompatible
>   lease was held on the file (see fcntl(2)).
> - `ENODEV` -  `pathname` refers to a device special file and no
>   corresponding device exists.  (This is a Linux kernel bug;
>   in this situation `ENXIO` must be returned.)
> - `ELOOP`  - Too many symbolic links were encountered in resolving
>   pathname.
>   `EISDIR` - `pathname` refers to a directory and the access requested
>   involved writing (that is, O_WRONLY or O_RDWR is set).
>   `ENOTDIR` -
>   A component used as a directory in `pathname` is not, in
>   fact, a directory, or `O_DIRECTORY` was specified and
>   `pathname` was not a directory.
> - `EPERM` -  The `O_NOATIME` flag was specified, but the effective user
>   ID of the caller did not match the owner of the file and
>   the caller was not privileged.

As well as various limits like number of open files (ENFILE, EMFILE), or ENOSPC disk space full.  The above is *not* a complete list, I just took one each the ways to get many (but not all) of the error codes.

---

As per funnydman's answer, you can look up the number -> symbolic meaning of error values in man pages.  Or look in `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h` (The full path may differ on some systems, and you'd only include this file indirectly, via `#include <errno.h>`)

Comment: Note that the man page only gives some possible errors.  Almost all system calls can also fail for any number of additional reasons, including things like `EFAULT`, `ESTALE`, `EMULTIHOP`, etc.

Comment: @fuz: `EFAULT` does get mentioned explicitly in most Linux system-call man pages, but not `ESTALE` or `EMULTIHOP`.  I'm familiar with NFS `ESTALE` stale fd (perhaps for `openat(2)`?  But yeah `read(2)` doesn't mention `ESTALE` either), but what's `EMULTIHOP`?

Comment: `EMULTIHOP` doesn't really occur anymore; IIRC it used to be generated when you try to access a file via NFS on an NFS mount on the NFS server (i.e. try to perform multiple NFS server hops).  I don't think it is generated these days. But for example a FUSE file system driver could return whatever error code it likes.  The important takeaway is to understand that the error causes given there are not exhaustive.

Comment: @fuz: Thanks, updated the answer to make it clear it's not exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

You can interpret this as values of `errno`, here is the [table](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/constants/errnos.md) (to list all of the codes use `errno -l`), also take a look at the [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). A part of the table:

| number | hex | symbol | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0x02 | ENOENT | No such file or directory |
| 13 | 0x0d | EACCES | Permission denied |

There is described a reason of such decision: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008711/9926721